# .Net IsNothing and Is Not Nothing causing exception in the Catch/Finally block when using Tasks

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, async-await

**Edit

1. Uncheck "Enable Optimizations" in the advance compilation options will not cause this error.
2. Removing the For Loop in the code will also not cause this problem.
3. Assigning the SF variable to a class level variable and checking that for nothing will not cause this problem.

End Edit**

My button click event handler has local variables SF and HostSystem which I populate from the SQLite DB using EF6.

The click event handler is denoted with Async method since it spawns a task and awaits on it.

In the finally block I check if the SF is empty by calling the IsNothing/ IsNot Nothing methods. However these constructs are throwing error ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object"). Happens only in Release mode.

My code which I can reproduce in 4.5.2 is below. Any help on why IsNothing is throwing error would be greatly appreciated. As always Thank you.

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Hostsystem As SupportSystem
    Dim SF As SendFile

    Try

        SF = db.SendFiles.FirstOrDefault(Function(SFile) SFile.Name = "DailySummary")
        Hostsystem = db.SupportSystems.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = SF.SupportSystemName)


        For i = 1 To 1

            Dim TaskSendFile As Task(Of String) = Task(Of String).Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                                                       Throw New ApplicationException("App Error")
                                                                                       Return ""
                                                                                   End Function)
            Await TaskSendFile

        Next

        MessageBox.Show("All Done")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message)
    Finally
        Try
            **'The below check is what is throwing error.** 
            If Not IsNothing(SF) Then
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Unexpected Error in the finally block. " + ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: [You should not be using StartNew without passing in a TaskSchedueller object](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Okay changed it to use Task.Run and I still get the error. Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. My understanding is that IsNothing on an object would not throw any exception and return the boolean result.  I unchecked "Enable Optimizations" in the advance compilation options and this problem does not happen.  Also removing that For Loop in my code also does not cause this problem.